# Use array to render select options

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, antd

This should be straitforward  thing but I cannot get to work even i tried different apporaches and also refered the stackoverflow existing solutions. I'm new to frontend work. I have react app (using typescript) and I'm using antd componets. I have following object

```
class User {
     locations: Location[];
}
class Location {
      name:string;
}
```

I want to render location names in select options. I tried

```
      <Select
            id="location"
            placeholder="Location"
          >
            {user.locations.map((loc) => {
              console.log('got -> ' + loc.name);
              <Option value={loc.name}>{loc.name}</Option>;
            })}
          </Select>
```

I get the exepected console log but nothing is rendered ( empty options list ) and there is no error. How to get this working

Comment: everything looks good. are you getting the number of user.locations as empty in the dropdown?

Comment: Yes. But the console log shows all the available data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from your map function, so it's just running and returning void. Since no component is returned, none is rendered. If you have multiple lines of code in an arrow function you have to use an explicit return. To quote MDN, `(arrow functions do not magically guess what or when you want to "return")`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Comment: Correct. this solved it.  {user.locations.map((loc) => (
              <Option value={loc.name}>{loc.name}</Option>;
            ))}